# Cplex Visual studio 2008 Error Example

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cplex

I'm beginner in using Cplex with visual studio.

I install both of them and follow the step of the manual.

When I try the example that I take from here : [example](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX86.html)

I have these errors:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ilcplex/ilocplex.h': No such file or directory

I try to find solutions but I can't find any.

do you have some suggestion?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the file c_cpp.htm that comes with CPLEX?

Comment: yes I did and I check it again. I follow everything

Answer (score 0):

did you add the dll libraries?
If you are using visual studio, in your c++ solution, project:

Configuration Properties -> c/c++ -> general,
in Additional include directories, add:
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\concert\include
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\CPLEX\include

Conguration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor, the
Preprocessor Denitions should be:
WIN32; DEBUG; CONSOLE;IL STD

Conguration Properties->Linker->Input, 
add to Additional Dependencies:
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\CPLEX\lib\x86_windows_vs2008\stat_mda\cplex122.lib
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\CPLEX\lib\x86_windows_vs2008\stat_mda\ilocplex.lib
C:\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122\concert\lib\x86_windows_vs2008\stat_mda\concert.lib

Manually, notice that the home directory depends on the place where CPLEX is installed.

Now you can:

#include "\ilcplex\ilocplex.h"

and some other .h from cplex you might want to play with !

Happy Linear Optimizing ! 
and if is not so linear, enjoy it more !! ;-)